# Unable to setup mongodb with Django

Tags: python, django, mongodb, nosql

My **Settings.py** file has

```
DATABASES = {
         'default' : {
                       'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
                       'NAME' : 'my_database'
                     }
             }
```

When I try to run the `django` I get the following error.
[I have attached the screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aUol.png)

I refered to this document  https://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/setup.html
MongoDb is up and running in the port 27017
Django Version:1.7
Python :3.4.3

Please suggest the solution to setup the mongodb with django.

Comment: Your question reads setup mongoDB with Django, so why do you use another ORM like mongo-engine for this? Why not use a [Django MongoDB connector](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found few **reasons** why MongoDb-engine(Python ORM form mongo database) tutorial was not working:

1. It supports Python version <3.5
2. And to connect to the database you should put the following code in 
   settings.py

   ```
   DATABASES = {
       'default' : {
                   'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
                  'NAME' : 'my_database'
                }
        }
   ```
3. They don't have active developer community

**Solution:**
Follow this tutorial for python>=3.5 and use mongoengine a python object data mapper for MongoDb.
http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html
to connect to the database put the following code in your project settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
        'default' : {
                   'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.dummy'
                    }
         }

from mongoengine import *
connect('dbname') #Database name that you want to use it for the project
```

For more info on [Development](https://github.com/MongoEngine/django-mongoengine)